# I keeping getting this error "cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount"

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am creating a mobile app using react native and website that utilizes the same firebase. For now I am trying to retrieve data from the firebase and I keep getting this error "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method." I am not sure if I am suppose of have a closing statement for the component.

```
import { View,Text,SafeAreaView,FlatList} from "react-native";
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {stringText} from './ReadNFCScreen';
import {styles} from "../stylesheets/welcomeScreenStyle"
import { List, ListItem} from "react-native-elements";
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import {config} from '../config/FirebaseAuth'


if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    var defaultApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    console.log(defaultApp.name);  // "[DEFAULT]"
}
let paredString = [];
export default class ProductList extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('checkoutScreen', stringText);
        let letters = stringText.toString();
        let array = letters.split(',');
        console.log('splice', array);
        let arr3 = [];
        let arr4 = [];
           
        for( let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)
        {
            
            if(array[i] != "Item"){
                arr3.push(array[i]);
               
                console.log("did it work:", array[i] );
            }
            else{
                console.log("Nop",array[i] );
            }
        }
        
        this.state = {
            paredString:stringText,
            array : array
        }; 
    }
    componentDidMount(){
    
        const myitems = firebase.database().ref("/Item")
        myitems.on("value", datasnap => {
            console.log('database Worked!!!', datasnap.val())
        })
    }
    render() {
        let {paredString,array } = this.state;
       
        return (
            <SafeAreaView>
                {/* <ScrollView> */}
                    <View style={styles.cardContainer}> 
                        <View style={styles.Text}>
                            {/* <Text style={styles.Textoutput}>{this.state.paredString}</Text>  */}
                            {/* <Text style={styles.Textoutput}>{this.state.array}</Text>  */}
                            <FlatList
                                data={[{key:array}]}
                                renderItem={({item}) => (
                                        
                                        <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}  </Text>
                                )}
                            />
                           
                        </View>
                    </View>
                {/* </ScrollView> */}
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your component ProductList mounts, you attach a listener. As the warning says, you should detach this listener when your component unmounts (in order to avoid a memory leak).

To do it, you can:

- store the database reference in your component's state
- in [componentWillUnmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount), [detach the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners) to the reference

Here is how it looks like:

```
export default class ProductList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            ...
            myItemsReference: null
        }; 
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const myitems = firebase.database().ref("/Item");
        myitems.on("value", datasnap => { ... });
        this.setState({myItemsReference: myitems});
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount(){
        if(this.state.myItemsReference) {
            myItemsReference.off("value");
        }
    }

    render() { ... }    
}
```